# How to add links to modal window in ExtJs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to create a list of links from a data store, and then use an XTemplate to loop through and display all the links in the data store.  I am trying to display the links in a modal window.  This is my code:

```
var win;

var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate("<p>Field1: {f1}, Field2: {f2} </p>").compile();
var data = {
    f1: 'a',
    f2: null
};

if(!win){
    win = new Ext.Window({
        el:'hello-win',
        layout:'fit',
        width:500,
        height:300,
        closeAction:'hide',
        plain: true,

        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'component',
                autoEl: {
                    html: '<input type="text">'
                },
                listeners: {
                    render: function(_component) {
                        _component.getEl().on('keyup', function(e) {
                            //console.log(this);
                            console.log(this.dom.childNodes[0].value);
                        });
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                title: 'test',
                height: 100,
                bodyPadding: 10,
                tpl: tpl,
                data: data,
                renderTo: Ext.get('hello-win')
            }
        ]
    });
}
win.show(this);
```

There are no errors in console, but the links never load.  It just shows my modal window and my textbox, but no links.  I would put in in a jsfiddle, but I don't know how (I'm new to ExtJs).

How can I display a list of links in this modal window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should not define `renderTo` in you `panel` config. Component defined in `items` array will be rendered to parent component automatically.
2. Your `window` have two items so you can not use `fit` layout. This layout can be used only if component have only one child component. You can remove layout definition and Ext JS framework will use `auto` layout or you can use some layout which support more child items, like [`hbox`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.HBox), [`vbox`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.VBox), etc.

Your code should look like this:

```
var win = new Ext.Window({
    width:500,
    height:300,
    closeAction:'hide',
    plain: true,
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            enableKeyEvents: true,
            listeners: {
               keyup: function(c) {
                   console.log(c.getValue());                       
               }
            }
        },
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'test',
            height: 100,
            bodyPadding: 10,
            tpl: tpl,
            data: data
        }
    ]
});
```

Also you should consider using [`textfield`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text) component instead of creating textfield by using `component` with `autoEl` config.

Comment: Thanks, nice answer.  I would like to see how you would do the `textfield` thing if you wouldn't mind sharing.